# Openlayers - Popover

Tags: openlayers, popover, markers

I am haveing the following issue, help will be appreciated. How do I access "img_src" object in the "featuresArray" outside the callback function "function(e)" after I click a feature? I need to pass it to another javascript file to render! Here is the https://jsfiddle.net/5fpc7otg/ Thank you very much

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!--JQuery-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css")>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js")></script>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="element"></div>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            var openStreetMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
                source:new ol.source.OSM(),
                visible:true,
                name:"openstreetmap"
            })

            var map = new ol.Map({
                layers:[openStreetMap],
                target:"map",
                view: new ol.View({
                    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([80,36]),
                    zoom:4
                })
            })

            var featuresArray = [];
            var feature1 = new ol.Feature
            ({
                geometry:new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([81,36],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857') ),
                name:"Feature1",
                img_src:"images/img_1.jpg",

            });

            var feature2 = new ol.Feature
            ({
                geometry:new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([85,39],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857') ),
                name:"Feature2",
                img_src:"images/img_2.jpg",

            });

            featuresArray.push(feature1);
            featuresArray.push(feature2);

    //style and icon
    var style = new ol.style.Style
    ({
        image:new ol.style.Icon
        ({
            anchor:[0.5, 5],
            src:'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/icon.png',
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            opacity: 0.75,
            scale:1
        })
    });


    var pointSource = new ol.source.Vector
    ({
        features:featuresArray
    });

    var pointMarker = new ol.layer.Vector
    ({
        source:pointSource,
        style:style

    });

    map.addLayer(pointMarker)

    var popup = new ol.Overlay({
        element:element,
        positioning:'bottom-center',
        stopEvent:false
    });

    map.addOverlay(popup);

    // Actions to be taken when clicked on the point
    map.on("click",function(e){
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel,function(feature, layer){
            return feature;

        });

        if(feature){

            popup.setPosition(e.coordinate);
            $(element).attr('data-placement', 'top');
            $(element).attr('data-html', true);
            $(element).attr('data-original-title', 'This is title');
            $(element).attr('data-content', feature.get('name'));
            $(element).popover('show');

        }

        else{
            $(element).popover('destroy');
        }

    });

    *****// I need to access this img_source here, sth like var x = feature.get('img_source')** and pass this variable x to another javascript file!*** 
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Add more details, please. I clearly did not give you the expected answer from your comment to my answer (deleted). So, what do you want to achieve? Too unclear to help you further at the moment.

Comment: Here is the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5fpc7otg/ var feature1 = new ol.Feature
  ({
   geometry:new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([81,36],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857') ),
   name:"Feature1",
   img_src:"images/img_1.jpg",
   
  }); Assume I need to acces img_src:"images/img_1.jpg" after I click a feature , how would I access it outside of the function? I need to pass it to another javascript file!

Comment: @Zevs: it is stil unclear, what exactly you want to do in your code?

Comment: @BhumiShah Inside of the callback function(e) I can call method feature.get('img_src') to get the key, but I need to pass this key to another javascript file. If  I do it outside of the function, I can not access it. How do I access this img_src?

Answer (score -1):

You can actually, declare a variable outside the map click event then assign its value once the click event happens.

```
      var img_src = '';
      // Actions to be taken when clicked on the point
      map.on("click", function(e) {
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
          return feature;

        });

        if (feature) {
          popup.setPosition(e.coordinate);
          $(element).attr('data-placement', 'top');
          $(element).attr('data-html', true);
          $(element).attr('data-original-title', 'This is title');
          $(element).attr('data-content', feature.get('name'));
          $(element).popover('show');
          img_src = feature.get('img_src')
          console.log(img_src) //you access this variable outside the function containingimg_src
        } else {
          $(element).popover('destroy');
        }
      });
```